# Qt web assembly: configure kit

Tags: c++, qt, build, emscripten, webassembly

I want to test out QT WebAssembly for my scientific program. 
Therefore, I installed emscripten.

```
$em++ --version
```

returns

```
emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like replacement) 1.38.30 (commit a5082b232617c762cb65832429f896c838df2483)...
```

Then I installed Qt using the Qt WebInstaller. 
In my installation directory I have a `wasm_32` folder which contains `bin` and `qmake`:

```
$ ~/Qt_web/5.13.2/wasm_32/bin/qmake --version
```

return

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.13.2 in /home/myName/Qt_web/5.13.2/wasm_32/lib
```

However, when I start Qt creator, click on `Projects` I see a Kit called: `Qt 5.13.2 WebAssembly` but I cannot select it (it is grayed out). 
When I click on manage Kits I saw that there is no C and C++ compiler selected for Qt 5.13.2.WebAssembly. 
[image: Kits]

I also get an warning when I change to `Qt Versions`. The warning says:

```
ABI detection failed: Make sure to use a matching compiler when building. No qmlscene installed.
```

This is a list of all compilers which are selectable: 
[image: compilers]

**Question:**

I do not really understand what `emscripten` has to do with all that. Is emscripten a compiler? If yes should it have been auto-selected by the `Qt 5.13.2 WebAssembly` kit?
How does a proper `Qt WebAssembly` kit look like?

If I select gcc as my compiler I get an error saying:

```
/home/myName/Qt_web/5.13.2/wasm_32/plugins/platforms/libqwasm.a:-1: error: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
```

**EDIT:**

When I open the qt maintenance tool and look at the installed packages I get the following: 
[image: qt_maintenance]

**EDIT2:**
After changing to Qt Creator `4.11.0-beta2 (4.10.83)` I was able to follow parts of [this](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtcreator-master/creator-setup-webassembly.html) description. I was able to select the Plugin, but I still can not change the Device type. 
[image: qtDeviceType]

Maybe it has to do with this error that I get now:
[image: error]

**EDIT3:**

seems as if my emscripten compiler has some problems. 
Is the compiler located in:

```
emscripten/emsdk/clang/e1.38.30_64bit/clang++
emscripten/emsdk/clang/e1.38.30_64bit/clang
```

One thing I noticed is that If I use `add` in QtCreator >> Kits >> Compilers and I select `Add >> WebAssembly >> C` It generates a new entry in `Manual >> C++ >> Emscripten Compiler` and not in `Manual >> C >> Emscripten Compiler`. Is this a problem?

**EDIT**

This is how my Compilers page looks like:
[image: newCompilers]

Comment: Yes, emscripten is a toolchain (including a compiler) and it needs to be set up in QtCreator as a Compiler in order to create a usable WA kit.  See https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtcreator-master/creator-setup-webassembly.html if you haven't yet.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. However, I can not select `Help > About Plugins > Device Support > WebAssembly`

Comment: Noticed this thread on the Qt interest list just recently... apparently latest QtCreator preview is recommended, though not clear if that's just for Mac or not.  https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2019-November/034154.html

Comment: Ok, using the newest Qt Creator preview helped a bit. I can select the plugin now, but I still can not change the Device type in the Kit. I'll add a screenshot to the question

Comment: Did you select your newly-added compilers in the WA Kit config? I think you should close the other question and centralize the info here (but just IMHO).

Comment: What is a `WA Kit config`? (I have Deleted the other question)

Comment: Sorry, the "Qt 5.13.2 WebAssembly" entry in the Kits config. It looks like you should be able to change the compilers in there (the selectors aren't disabled).

Comment: I can only select my manually made compiler entries for the `C++` Compiler, not for the `C` compiler. However, as soon as I select I get an error sign after the `Qt 5.13.2 WebAssembly` line

Comment: I'm about at my limit on how much I know about this... :)  But I'm wondering if the ABI in the manually added compiler is correct (what is the error when you hover over the red error sign in the kit?). And why it's complaining about the auto-detected Emscripten compiler entries. And yea there should be valid Compiler entries in both C and C++ groups.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The error just says that the compiler cannot produce for this QT version. I'll try it later today on a windows machine.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with QtCreator-5.15 on Windows 10. Since I am a Linux guy my knowledge of Windows is somewhat limited, but I got as far you have. Any new insights into this issue? The Installation for QtCreator should be more self-explanatory and contain all the tools you need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73500781/4631798 Was the solution for me, Python was not correctly set up.

Answer (score 5):

1. You need to copy the .emscripten file from emsdk directory to your home (/home/myUsername).
2. You need to fix the paths in the file manually (See example below).

Notice that .emscripten file , at least in the version (1.39.8) i am using, is a python script (maybe a bug?)

example file before edit:

```
import os
emsdk_path = os.path.dirname(os.environ.get('EM_CONFIG')).replace('\\', '/')
NODE_JS = emsdk_path + '/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node'
LLVM_ROOT = emsdk_path + '/upstream/bin'
BINARYEN_ROOT = emsdk_path + '/upstream'
EMSCRIPTEN_ROOT = emsdk_path + '/upstream/emscripten'
TEMP_DIR = emsdk_path + '/tmp'
COMPILER_ENGINE = NODE_JS
JS_ENGINES = [NODE_JS]
```

after edit:

```
import os
emsdk_path = os.path.dirname(os.environ.get('EM_CONFIG')).replace('\\', '/')
NODE_JS = '/home/myUsername/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node'
LLVM_ROOT = '/home/myUsername/upstream/bin'
BINARYEN_ROOT = '/home/myUsername/upstream'
EMSCRIPTEN_ROOT = '/home/myUsername/upstream/emscripten'
TEMP_DIR = '/home/myUsername/tmp'
COMPILER_ENGINE = NODE_JS
JS_ENGINES = [NODE_JS]
```

When above steps are completed qt creator was able to detect the Emscripten Compiler with no errors.

Comment: I worked out to this answer before finding this answer. If you do a detect of the compilers, you'll see stupid paths that say emsdk_path + ... -- that was a big hint.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try in  the kits tab to set your compiler with this values?

Compiler:
C compiler x86 64 e1.38.27_bit
C++ compiler x86 64 e1.38.27_bit

Qt version:
path to you qmake built  with webassembly, for example webassembly binaries or your custom binaries.

Qt mkspec:
wasm-emscripten

Hope this information helps, if you face any other problem let me know.