# Associate QT WebAssembly with Emscripten

Tags: c++, qt, webassembly, emscripten

We have developed a desktop application with Qt in Python language. We want to transform the desktop version to the web version.

For Qt 5.13 or higher, there is a plugin called WebAssembly, which uses Emscripten to do code translation.

**Problem**

We have installed Qt 5.13 and Qt 5.14, Web Assembly but we're having trouble getting Qt to recognize Emscripten. Either it does not recognize Emscripten or, if you recognize it, you do not understand the Emscripten directory.

Are we installing Emscripten wrong? Do we need to know any details?

**Snapshots**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try to manually set the paths for `emcc` and `em++`?

Comment: check my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63867803/8548566) on a similar issue. It might help

Answer (score 0):

Qt for WebAssembly is meant for C++, and not for Qt for python, even though python can run on WebAssembly, the python libs most likely won't ever be ported to WebAssembly, since is quite a technical challenge, also because Qt wasm apps are statically linked, and this poses a big problem for python libs. If your app relies heavily on QML, you should be able to port and run your app in the browser. If you want to do some quick testing you can use Felgo WebAssembly tools like the web editor https://felgo.com/web-editor or the fully fledged Web IDE https://ide.felgo.com

Answer (score -1):

You have to run: `source /path/to/emsdk/emsdk_env.sh` prior to running QtCreator but within the same context if that makes sense.

---

**Here's an example of how to fix this**

- Create the file `em-qtcreator.sh` in your HOME folder and do something like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    source /path/to/emsdk/emsdk_env.sh
    /path/to/qtcreator
```

Now, just execute that script by using

```
chmod +x em-qtcreator.sh 

./em-qtcreator.sh
```

This should allow QtCreator to auto-detect emscripten, otherwise you'll have to manually add the emcc compilers in the build configuration