# QtCreator cannot find the emscripten compiler

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator, webassembly, emscripten

I followed [this](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-setup-webassembly.html) guide and installed emscripten using [emsdk](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html) and activated it.Then I configured my `$PATH` as instructed by the emsdk itself and also sourced `emsdk-master/emsdk_env.sh`.Now I can access both `emcc` and `em++` in the terminal.The file `~/.emscripten` is also present(this is the file that QtCreator will fetch to find the path of compilers for WASM).

The `WebAssembly` kit for Qt also has been installed by the Qt `Maintenance Tool`.

Now in the Kit configuration in the QtCreator I get this(QtCreator is opened via terminal after sourcing `emsdk_env.sh`):

[image]

It cannot determine the path of compilers by itself.

In the **Compilers** tab I manually added a compiler as follows:

[image]

But I get this error in the **Kits** tab after that:

[image]

What does that mean? What did I skip? Does anybody ever have the experience of doing this?

Also changing the compiler from `em++` to `wasm-32-wasi-clang++` or `clang++` doesn't change anything.

[image]

By the way if I use that kit I get:

```
Error while parsing file whatever.pro. Giving up.
Project ERROR: Cannot run target compiler 'em++'. Output:
===================
===================
Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
```

And please don't tell me that this question is the duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58970301/qt-web-assembly-configure-kit) because it isn't(mine has more details) and there's no useful answer for that after 9 months at this time.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and so far it seems that Qt Creator is not getting the sourced environment, even thought it was started from a shell where 'source emsdk_env.sh' was run. The error ("... Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?") is exacly what /path/to/Qt/wasm_32/bin/qmake says when you have forgot to source, and in Qt Creator's 'General Messages' log, there is "shared:ERROR: BINARYEN_ROOT is set to empty value in .emscripten", which is what /path/to/emscripten/em++ says when you forgot to source. I can successfully build a wasm app with qmake from command line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @foolo.I tried running the WASM ```qmake``` for my project and got the warning about version incompatibility between the emsdk which was used by Qt 5.14(1.38.27) and the emsdk currently installed(2.0.0 i,e latest).So I deleted the emsdk entirely and began from scratch,this time by installing 1.38.27 and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63717267/failed-to-run-llvm-optimizations-using-clang-for-webassmebly).Not sure what's causing that.How did you manage to build a project successfully?

Comment: So far I only built one of Qt's sample applications. I installed Qt 5.15 and Creator with the installer from https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer and emsdk 1.39.8 from the repo. Then navigated to the project (~/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.15.0/widgets/mainwindows) and ran `~/Qt/wasm_32/bin/qmake` and `make`. It created web files in `sdi` folder. I tested it with `~/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emrun --browser=firefox sdi/sdi.html` which actually runs the text editor in the browser :) I created a gist with detailed steps here: https://gist.github.com/foolo/a728e971bdd79b37fff04ca8b65b847c

Comment: @foolo I got ```Qt/5.14.2/wasm_32/include/QtCore/qcompilerdetection.h:591:6: error: Qt requires a C++11 compiler and yours does not seem to be that``` besides lots of other strange errors like ```error: unknown type
      name 'constexpr'``` for that example project.After adding ```CONFIG+=c++11``` that error turned into ```Failed to run llvm optimizations:``` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63717267/failed-to-run-llvm-optimizations-using-clang-for-webassmebly).Needless to say I sourced ```emsdk_env.sh``` beforehand.Any idea? Should I upgrade my Qt or start from scratch?

Comment: It seems that you are using Qt 5.14 and emsdk 1.38.27 fastcomp clang, which should be a good combo according to https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_WebAssembly, but maybe the error is still related to that combo. I'm using Qt 5.15 and emsdk 1.39.8, so my only advice would be to try the newer version.

Comment: check my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63867803/8548566) on a similar issue. It might help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run:
emsdk install
and
emsdk activate
within emsdk folder, not from a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup the emsdk inside QtCreator => Preferences => Devices => WebAssembly. Afterwards the compiler should be auto-detected by Qt Creator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was, that python was not correctly recognized.
In my case the symbolic link /usr/bin/python was not set
`ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`
Afterwards the emsripten Toolchain is recognized automatically in QtCreator.